# What makes this use of jScroll in a Laravel 8 application fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, infinite-scroll

I am working on a **blogging application in Laravel 8**.

The **ArticlesController** controller I have this method to display the single article and its *comments*:

```
class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

    // More code

    public function show($slug) {
        // Single article
        $article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug);
        $old_article = Article::where('id', '<', $article->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
        $new_article = Article::where('id', '>', $article->id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();

        // Comments
        $commentsQuery = Comment::where(['article_id' => $article->id, 'approved' => 1])->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        $comments = $commentsQuery->paginate(10);
        $comments_count = $commentsQuery->count();

        return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/single', 
            array_merge($this->data, [
                'categories' => $this->article_categories,
                'article' => $article,
                'old_article' => $old_article,
                'new_article' => $new_article,
                'comments' => $comments,
                'comments_count' => $comments_count,
                'tagline' => $article->title,
                ])
            );
    }

}
```

In the view I have this for the comments list:

```
<div id="commentsList">
  <ol class="commentlist">
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <li class="depth-1 comment">
      <div class="comment__avatar">
        <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $comment->user->avatar) }}" alt="" width="50" height="50">
      </div>
      <div class="comment__content">
        <div class="comment__info">
          <div class="comment__author">{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}</div>
          <div class="comment__meta">
            <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</div>
            <div class="comment__reply">
              <a class="comment-reply-link" href="#0">Reply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment__text">
          <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ol>

  {{ $comments->links() }}
</div>
```

#### The goal

I want to replace the comments pagination with an "infinite scroll", with the help of **[jScroll](https://jscroll.com/)**.

For this purpose, I have:

```
$('#commentsList nav').hide();
$(function() {
    $('#commentsList').jscroll({
        autoTrigger: true,
        loadingHtml: '<span>Loading...</span>',
        padding: 0,
        nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
        contentSelector: '.commentlist > li',
        callback: function() {
            $('#commentsList nav').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

#### The problem

The code above should append the `<li class="depth-1 comment"></li>` elements to the `<ol class="commentlist"><ol>` but instead it does the folowing:

- wraps the loaded list items in a `<div class="jscroll-added"></div>`
- puts the `<div class="jscroll-added"></div>` element *below* the comments list instead of *inside* it.

#### Questions

1. What causes this bug?
2. What is the easiest fix?

Comment: Have you tried $('.commentsList').jscroll({
Don't you need to apply jscroll to the ol not the outer div?

Comment: @Razvan Zamfir could you add the code related with the pagination? I'm not sure `nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a'` is correct

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that it just doesn't get the complex selector.  It is either obviously not made to be used with ol element (so the numbers would start from 1 again and again for each new request). Using only divs would spare you this type of issues.

I managed to achieve the result you want with these steps:

1.Moved the {{ $comments->links() }} into the ol element (so it could
be taken in each new request).

2.Changing the contentSelector to '.commentlist' only.

```
contentSelector: '.commentlist',
```

3.The callback function becomes:

```
callback: function() {
    $('#commentsList nav').remove();
    var content = $('.jscroll-added').contents().unwrap().html();
    $('ol.commentlist:first').append(content);
    $('ol.commentlist').not(':first').remove();
}
```

And this way it would take the li elements, append them to the existing ol and get rid of the newly created ol.

Cheers

Comment: I appreciate your involvement a lot. However, the pagination has to stay _outside_ the <ol> element.